# Azure Pipelines YAML - error when using variable group for "Deploy Web App" azureSubscription input

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I defined variable groups for my various environments with a variable `board.subscription` which specifies the Azure Service Connection to be used in WebApp deployment.

These variable groups are referenced for the deployment jobs:

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)-$(Rev:r)

trigger:
  - master
  - dev
  - feature/*
  - bug/*

stages:
  - stage: build
...
  - stage: deploy_test
    displayName: deploy to TEST
    dependsOn: build
    variables:
      - group: 'Test-Deployment'
    jobs:
      - template: azure-pipelines/deploy.yml
        parameters:
          environment: TEST

  - stage: deploy_prod
    displayName: deploy to PROD
    dependsOn: deploy_test
    variables:
      - group: 'Production-Deployment'
    jobs:
      - template: azure-pipelines/deploy.yml
        parameters:
          environment: PROD
```

and then the variable is used in the `deploy.yml` file:

```
parameters:
  environment: ''
  agentImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    displayName: deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}
    environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    pool:
      vmImage: ${{ parameters.agentImage }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop
            - task: AzureWebApp@1
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '$(board.subscription)'
                appName: '$(board.functionapp)'
```

However when queueing the pipeline, the expression seems to be evaluated before the variable is populated which leads to this error:

```
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job TEST: Step input azureSubscription references service connection $(board.subscription) which could not be found.
```

When I use a literal value for `azureSubscription`it is working fine.

**Question:** Can this evaluation be delayed or is there another way for not having the Service Connection Name hardcoded in the YAML file?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. How did you solve this?

Comment: in the end I gave up and hard coded the azureSubscription value in the YML file

Comment: Looks like we're not the only ones https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7586

Answer (score 0):

I tested with variable group and got the same error as you:

[image]

If the subscription is only define to a variable in yaml and then referenced in the AzureWebApp task, the pipeline will not get this error.

```
variables:
  azureSubscription: connectionName
  # -group : test1

stages:
...
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: 1123'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: webApp
        appName: xxx
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification Hugh Lin - I guess I would need to reduce my question to "variable group" because just putting the connectionName in a single variable would take away the effect of what I want to achieve - have different connectionNames for various environments

Comment: with "azureSubscription: ${{board.subscription}}" I get : /azure-pipelines/deploy.yml (Line: 19, Col: 36): Unrecognized value: 'board'. Located at position 1 within expression: board.subscription

Comment: same goes for "azureSubscription: '${{ board.subscription }}'"